A captured image is not identifing face in Google ML KIT with Flutter and Node JS
There is a system with face search with Nodejs API. With uploading an image from computer/laptop to search it works fine. But as we upload an image for image search using Flutter it does not match the result.
We tried both the camera and image_picker extensions with and without Google ML Kit. However, it works with some mobile phones such as Oppo and Vivo. With Samsung and OnePlus that did not work. Is there any mobile-specific configuration that we need to consider?
